# Reactive Form Components

Tags: angular, forms, reactive

We use many Angular material fields and they are all presented the same. I want a way to simplify any changes coming from UI designers and maintenance later.

How can I create a component that reduces this block of HTML  (just example code)

```
<div fxFlex>
  <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>The Label</mat-label>
       <input matInput formControlName="controlName" ... >
       <mat-hint>*Required</mat-hint> 
       <mat-error *ngIf="controlName.invalid && controlName.touched">{{errorMessage}}</mat-error>
   </mat-form-field>
<div>
```

down to something sensible like this

```
<custominput  formControlName="controlName" [errorMessage]="Error" ...></custominput>
```

I've tried to follow along with these tutorials without success.

[Angular Custom Fields Blog](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/)

[Angular material Custom Fields](https://v11.material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control)

I really don't understand how to apply to an input field essentially.
This is what I'm left with at present.

TS file contents

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInput } from '@angular/material/input';

@Component({
  selector: 'hr-textinput',
  template:`
    <div [ngClass]="labelPosition">
      <mat-label>{{label}}</mat-label>
      <mat-form-field>
          <input #inputFieldIdentifier matInput formControlName={{controlName}} id={{id}} (blur)="onTouched()"> 
          <mat-error *ngIf="controlName.invalid">{{errorMsg}}</mat-error> 
          <mat-hint  *ngIf="mandatory">*Required</mat-hint>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./textinput.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi:true,
      useExisting: TextinputComponent
    }
  ]
})

export class TextinputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
  @ViewChild('inputFieldIdentifier') inputField: MatInput;

  @Input() controlName:  string = "";
  @Input() mandatory: boolean = false;
  @Input() label: string = "";
  @Input() errorMsg = "";                     
  
  @Input() labelPosition: string = "before";  // "before" and  "above"  are the two options available at present
  @Input() id: string = "";                   

  touched = false;
  disabled = false;

  constructor() { 
    
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.id = `${this.controlName}_ID`;
  }

  onChange = (value) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  writeValue(fieldValue: any): void {
    this.inputField.value = fieldValue;
  }
  registerOnChange(onChangeFn: any): void {
    this.onChange = onChangeFn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(onTouchedFn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = onTouchedFn;
  }
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.inputField.disabled = isDisabled;
  }
  markAsTouched() {
    if (!this.touched) {
      this.onTouched();
      this.touched = true;
    }
  }
}
```

SCSS file contents

```
.above {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;  
  align-items: left;
  .mat-form-field {
    padding-top: 6px;  
  }
}

.before {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;  
  align-items: center;
  .mat-form-field {
    padding-left: 12px;  
  }
}
```

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated as I've clearly no idea.

[StackBlitz Demo of Issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xzaefy?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: can you provide stackblitz?

Comment: Ok I've created a stackblitz to show the error I get. Please not that was my first time I've used stackbltiz - so be patient :) 
thanks for the help

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xzaefy?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: For those wondering - the actual error is - The app cannot find my 'form' problem

Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive. You'll want to add a formGroup
directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing the `The app cannot find my 'form'` error is because you are using the `formControlName` directive inside the component that is supposed to be implementing the `formControlName` interface. If you remove the `formControlName` directive from your custom input component template, you will no longer see that error.

In other words, when implementing `ControlValueAccessor` you are essentially telling Angular that your component knows how to use the `formControlName` directive and so the `formControlName` directive should be put on your custom component when instantiating it. i.e.

```
<hr-textinput formControlName="myField">
</hr-textinput>
```

I forked your stackblitz to show a working form: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-onycez?

Comment: Excellent, I see it working now.
Thankyou so much for the help !

Comment: I haven't been able to get the standard validation working correctly with this. Would anybody have any thoughts. I didn't think I would need to write custom validators to do the same things as the defaults ? thanks

Comment: My example didn't fully implement the ControlValueAccessor. We need to tell the forms API to update whenever an input event occurs. To do this, listen for any input changes on the input element. When an input event occurs, call the registered `onChange` callback with the input value.

I've updated the stackblitz to show this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-onycez?

For more info see: https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor#registeronchange

Comment: I honestly do not know how to say thankyou enough for your help :)

Comment: You're welcome :)